# Как работает Cassandra и Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

Собственно сабж!
Как я понимаю в теории по мануалам, конфиги кассандры не трогаются, в хадупе указывается нода в кассандре? или я чтото пропустил?
и еще, после интеграции -- как оно вообще работает? Мне код надо править, чтобы задействовать hadoop? Не могу примеры найти :(

Подскажите может что-нибудь?

Comment: что? никто не работает с этими зверьми??

Comment: Видимо из завсегдатаев никто. 

Название знакомое. Знаю что люди с ним мучаются. 

Говорят у IBM хороший пакет со всеми настройками, поддержкой и консультациями есть за деньги.

Comment: Мне вообще понять бы) у мя datastax enterprise есть. Но там все это из-коробки работает, а я хочу понять как оно поотдельности настраивается и работает.

Comment: я вот с Redis имею гемор, здесь на форуме очень мало людей, кто может подсказать по этим DB. Redis похож на Cassandra. Если что пиши - помогу с Redis

Comment: @IOleg спасибо, но нужно именно кассандра.

Comment: Redis  похож на Cassandra как я на балерину

Answer (score 1):

Я работаю с Кассандрой без Хадупа. Вместо Хадупа использую шторм http://storm.apache.org (аналог Hadoop Streaming). В своих источниках для шторма используются драйвера Кассандры. Специально конфиги не трогаются. Вместо Кассандры я с таким же успехом мог использовать и MySQL. Думаю, что и в Халупе аналогичный подход (могу ошибаться).
Вместо Kafka (сервер очередей) использую редис (как очередь). Единственное, что остается - это ZooKeeper для координации.

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы как-то вопрос поконкретнее сформулировали что ли,непонятно в чем у вас проблема. Для работы с данными/источниками данных в hadoop используется InputFormat и его сабклассы,для баз данных - это DBInputFormat.[Пример использования](https://www.edureka.co/blog/using-dbinputformat-in-mapreduce-to-transfer-data-from-sql-db-to-nosql-db/).